# mysql table changes rowcount on each page refresh in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx

in my application, each time I refresh page I get a different data.

After check the code, I guess the problem is with mysql, because in phpmyadmin, each time I refresh page two of my tables changes it's rowcount

I tried to turn off mysql cache and run optimize, check and analyze tables, but no success

It is running with nginx and ubuntu on digitalocean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running innodb tabels? If so you cannot rely on the table's reported row count--it's just an estimate (a crazy one at that).

Do a `select count(primary_key) from table` to get the correct count.  If that's still showing changing numbers, turn on your db's query log an watch what's going on.

Comment: this query returns always the same count, thanks! the tables are innodb, should I change this? what can cause this problem? yesterday I got the same problem for 2 hours, then it normalized, and now its happening again

Comment: There is no 'fix', it's just the way innodb stores data that it can't accurately give a row count without running a count query (dont' do a count(*) though).  See this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624408/why-is-innodbs-show-table-status-so-unreliable